# Glide along with FirebaseStorage not fetching latest photo even when online

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am using Glide along with FirebaseStorage to fetch the photos stored in FirebaseStorage and show in the app. The problem is when photos were updated in the storage, The updated photos are not fetched, instead the old photos are being shown in the app. The device is online and its never updating the latest photos.

```
thirdPhotoStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("photos/${key}/3.jpg")

GlideApp.with(this)
                    .load(thirdPhotoStorageReference)
                    .override(screenWidth, screenHeight)
                    .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

                            showPhotoImageView(thirdPhotoImageView)
                            return false
                        }

                        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

                            hidePhotoImageView(thirdPhotoImageView)

                            return false
                        }
                    })
                    .placeholder(circularProgressDrawable3)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(thirdPhotoImageView)
```

```
@GlideModule
class MyAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {

    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference::class.java, InputStream::class.java,
                FirebaseImageLoader.Factory())
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Note: When I update the photo, It replaces the existing photo 3.jpg with latest.

Comment: Sounds like the images are being cached by Glide which is generally a good thing for performance and cost management.

Comment: Yeah looks like the images are being cached on device. But at the same time I want them to be updated when the actual file at FirebaseStorage is updated. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: You will have to build a way to query something that tells you if the underlying content changed.

Answer (score 1):

Found an approach to solve the issue and posting it if someone has the same problem.

I was able to get the updated photos using the signature functionality of Glide. Please see the code below

```
thirdPhotoStorageReference.metadata.addOnSuccessListener {

                GlideApp.with(this)
                        .load(thirdPhotoStorageReference)
                        .signature(ObjectKey(it.updatedTimeMillis))
                        .override(screenWidth, screenHeight)
                        .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

                                showPhotoImageView(thirdPhotoImageView)
                                return false
                            }

                            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

                                hidePhotoImageView(thirdPhotoImageView)

                                return false
                            }
                        })
                        .placeholder(circularProgressDrawable3)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(thirdPhotoImageView)

            }
```

The key here is the `signature(ObjectKey(it.updatedTimeMillis))` which gets the update time of storage object and lets glide to refresh it.